# google form response in adding same event details into google calendar through google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how to create a google script which prevents any same entry from google form response to be added into google calendar

so far i have figure out a code to add entries from google form response in google sheet and add it as a event in the google calendar. just wondering if there is a work around in preventing same entry data from being added into google calendar

the result should help prevent same data entry to be not added into the google calendar

below is the current code that i have
currently the code can only add entries from google form response in google sheet to google calendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOeSz.jpg)